# Overloading of operator[]

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, subscript-operator

What are the scenarios which may need to overload the subscript operator?

And what has the assert function got to do with this? I see in most cases of subscript overloading use of assert, would need an explanation on that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might overload the `[]` operator on a custom container, to provide a syntactically/semantically clearer way of accessing elements.

For example `my_container[3] = 9;` is somewhat clearer than `my_container.set(3, 9);`

Of course, you could overload the `[]` to do essentially anything, but you probably shouldn't. You could, for example, cause `my_object[3]` to increment `my_object` by 3, but semantically the `[]` operator conveys lookup-by-index, and it's always better to have your interfaces conform to expectations.

You could use `assert` for quick-and-dirty bounds checking; it will cause your program to die messily, which is always preferable to introducing subtle memory corruption. The benefit is that `assert` is a macro which can be compiled out of production code, meaning you may pay the overhead of bounds-checking your container in development and not in production with no modification to your code.

Answer (score 3):

You would consider overloading `operator[]` for classes where the operation (index( by a single field makes sense, as it is the case of vectors (index by position) set or maps (index by key). Note that if there is more than one dimension by which to index, it might make sense to use a different operator (`operator()`), as `operator[]` takes a single argument. You should probably read the C++FAQ lite entry on [Operator Overloading](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/operator-overloading.html).

In general `assert` is unrelated to `operator[]` (or any other operator). `assert` is a way of determining at runtime that some preconditions to the operation are met, and should be used to *fail fast* and *fail hard* when you detect that some of your invariants are broken.

Comment: Just a note, but if there is more than one dimension, the classical solution is to return a proxy, which also overloads [].  One can argue about the two approachs, but the proxy solution does provide the same syntax as C style arrays of arrays, i.e. c[i][j].

Comment: @James Kanze: That is, in most cases not the best idea. Read [13.10](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/operator-overloading.html#faq-13.10) and the following points from the linked C++FAQ.

Comment: @David Rodriguez The FAQ expresses the opinion of one author.  Opinions
on this question differ.  (Several of the statements in the FAQ,
particularly those concerning performance, are simply false.  One
solution maps easily to the other, so performance is never a reason to
prefer one over the other.)  I rather prefer the use of () myself---I've
been influenced by Barton and Nackman---but both options are valid, and
deserve to be mentionned, and judging from the places I've worked, the
[][] option seems to be the more popular, and to be considered the more
"classical" solution.

Comment: @James Kanze: No, not really. It is trivial to provide the `operator()` on top of the `operator[]` composition, but not in the reverse direction (\*). Also that FAQ is not the work of an author but rather the result of pulling frequently asked questions from comp.lang.c++. (\*) Ok, trivially it is, if you provide a function with N arguments, and `operator[]` return proxies that only contain a pointer to the object + the argument to the operator, the last level of such proxying calling the original function.

Comment: ... but that shows that you have solved the issue by providing a multiple argument function (why not just call it `operator()`?) and added a bunch of boiler plate code just to make it look like `operator[]`.

Comment: Mapping one to the other is trivial.  In both directions: the usual
implementation of the proxy would be to simply store the already given
arguments, and forward to a member function in its overloaded operators.
(Even with the (,) form, you'll often want a proxy.)  And in it's
current state, the FAQ is the opinion of one particular person.  I don't
think that there is anywhere near a consensus about this, and a lot of
people favor maintaining the same syntax as for C style 2D arrays.

Comment: @James Kanze: Given the `(,)` notation, under what circumstances would you want a proxy? What would you gain from having it?

Comment: @David Rodriguez Syntax.  Some people prefer the traditional C notation.  If your users are among those, you support [][].  If your users come from the Fortran world, you use (,).  If they're a mixed lot, and they're on the same project, you get some sort of consensus, put it in the coding guidelines, and implement it.  If you're writing a third party library, where you don't know your users, you implement both.

Answer (score 1):

Well with my limited knowledge on this, i can say, in situations when the classes hold a sequence of elements. Vector/String for example. For assert you may want to check out this site.  [--LINK--](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cassert/assert/)

Answer (score 1):

**Assert has absolutely nothing to do** with the indexing operator `operator[]` **per se**.

Assert is used to check preconditions/invariants in debug builds, so violations of these are trapped before going into production.

Indexing operators are prone to `index out of range` type of situation, which *might* explain why you seem to be noticing them there more often than elsewhere. I use assert basically at least once in every parameterized function, and several times per class (checking invariants).

*HTH*

Answer (score 1):

You might overload `operator[]`  if you are implementing a class that is a collection or a wrapper for a collection.  For me, I would only overload `operator[]` if the operation could be executed in constant or near-constant time, since that is how array indexing performs.  It may make sense to use it to look up values in a hash table, but not to index into a linked list.

If you are finding `asserts` used in implementations of `operator[]`, it is likely to enforce that the index argument is within the range of the collections.  This, IMO, is an *incorrect* use of `assert`, since `assert` should be used to catch internal programming errors, rather than you program being called the wrong way.  An end user or client application should never see an assertion error.  The other possibility is that this class is only used internally, in which case an assertion error would reveal an internal programming error, not a wrong argument passed in by a client.

Comment: Good mention of time constraint; that is what prevents the operator from occurring on many STL containers. Though they allow log time in the case of `map`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change the range of your index (e.g. indexing from 1 instead of from 0), or represent a higher-dimensional array by a one-dimensional array?